# Font increase animation doesn't work JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i am trying to recreate a simple jQuery animation with JavaScript. And it doesn't work. I would be very happy if you tell me what is wrong, because for me it seems right. Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").animate({fontSize: "100px"}, "slow");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:200px;width:600px;">Hello World</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And below is the JavaScript animation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>This is a title!!!</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: #98bf21; width: 200px; height: 600px;">Hello World!</div>
    <button onclick="startFontIncrease()">Click me</button>
    <script>
    function startFontIncrease() {
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
        var fontSize = element.style.fontSize;
        var id = setInterval(increaseFont, 5);
        function increaseFont() {
            if (fontSize == 100) {
                clearInterval(id);
            }
            else {
                fontSize++;
                element.style.fontSize = fontSize;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous problems with the transcription to plain JS.

To begin with, you have not set an initial font-size in the inline style and it is thus an empty string when you try to access it. So the HTML should be like this:

```
<div style="background-color: #98bf21; width: 200px; height: 300px; font-size: 12px;">
   Hello World!
</div>
```

Then, you must get the initial font size out of the font-size increasing function and you must also parse it to make sure you get the number (and not the "12px" string, otherwise it will be NaN when you try to increment).

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
var fontSize = parseInt(element.style.fontSize);

function startFontIncrease() {

    var id = setInterval(increaseFont, 5);
    function increaseFont() {
        if (fontSize == 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        }
        else {
            fontSize++;
            element.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving slow attribute,adjust them in milliseconds if possible.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").animate({fontSize: "100px"}, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation doesn't work because the fontSize you get for the div is ""
What you have to is

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",startFontIncrease);
  function startFontIncrease() {
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
    var fontSize = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'));

    var id = setInterval(increaseFont, 100);

    function increaseFont() {
      if (fontSize == 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        fontSize++;
        element.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
      }
    }
  }
```

For the jQuery version Hameed Syed seams to be correct.